# Jquery Exit popup with custom text

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to use jquery Exit popup in my shoping cart website.If any person try  to exit from website then there would be popup of 10% discount to stay him on that page.
I searched alot but there are only example of Confirm box.

Can anyone show me the example to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is simply not possible. If you could do whatever you want when user tries to leave the page you could e.g. never let him to do so. In other words - you can not display custom popup INSTEAD of the default dialog.

What you CAN do is to display standard dialog and do something in background. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        window.discountPercent = 10;
        $("body").append("<strong>You now have a " + discountPercent + "% discount!</strong>");
        return 'You will get a discount if you dont leave. Still wanna leave?'; 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi rocky  "You now have a 10% discount!" this display on page.....i want to display it in popup...any help???Thanks

Comment: So put the message into return of the function. Or if you want to display it in another popup you can call `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` which expects you have hidden `<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">You now have a 10% discount!</div>` on the page.